# Вычислить откуда идёт перебор учётных записей

Tags: windows, консоль, защита, windows-server-2008-r2, перебор

На Windows Server 2008 R2 поднят терминальный сервер. На него же проброшен порт наружу. Снаружи порт не стандартный. С недавнего времени идёт перебор учётных записей. Как вычислить атакующий IP? И как на будущее защититься от такого? Понимаю, что есть стратегии защиты типа белый список IP или полновесный развёрнутый PKI и доступ по сертификатам. Но сейчас идёт перебор явно с машины одного из наших сотрудников, так как список сессий на сервере и список сессий на маршрутизаторе, который стоит на периметре совпадает. Кроме того, собрал список адресов, с которых ходят сотрудники.

Comment: Ну если сотрудника - проверь его комп пачкой антивирей.

Comment: Как вычислить какого сотрудника проверять?

Comment: Ну логины не светятся в журнале? При smb и rdp обращении - это всё видится.

Comment: угу, вот что фиксируется в журнале

03/28/2020 16:06:42Учетной записи не удалось выполнить вход в систему.

Тип входа:                      3

Учетная запись, которой не удалось выполнить вход:
        ИД безопасности:                S-1-0-0
        Имя учетной записи:             ROUTER
        Домен учетной записи:          


Сведения о сети:
        Имя рабочей станции:   
        Сетевой адрес источника:        -
        Порт источника:         -

Comment: ip не светится? Эммм... ну копай другие журналы, метка времени у тебя же есть.

Comment: какие? (:
если бы я знал какие, то вопроса бы не было, не так ли?

Comment: Ну например логи роутера, фаерволла. Опять же, кто мешает спрятать сервак за sstp\openvpn?

Comment: Что мешает? Отсутствие времени, например. Я задал конкретный вопрос - как вычислить ip переборщика, а о том, что есть другие способы я писал.

Comment: netstat -p tcp|find/i":3389" и искать среди них "вредителя", либо воспользоваться любым аналогичным монитором активности tcp-портов(tcpview и т.п.). Но это не решение. Проблема в том, что прекращена поддержка W2k8 и уязвимости RDP - больше закрываться НЕ БУДУТ. Сервер будет в относительно ближайшее время автоматически заражен и использован для атаки на внутреннюю инфраструктуру. Продумайте меры по изоляции сервера и реагированию на угрозы: VPN, антивирус, SIEM и т.д.

Comment: что значит "автоматически заражён"? Если можно в технических терминах

Comment: Эпидемию "НеПети" помните? использовалась уязвимость SMB-сервиса. Аналогичные эксплойты существуют для RDP. Это лишь вопрос времени, когда будет заражен незащищенный сервер. Пользовательский ПК уже скомпрометирован.

Comment: но это не означает "автоматически"

Comment: Атака **УЖЕ** идет в автоматическом режим, или Вы думаете там кто-то вручную пароли набирает?! Пока она идет путем перебора. При наличии боевого кода (Bluekeep), которые без сомнений будет скоро доступен, атака будет проведена на множество доступных серверов в Сети, в том числе и на Ваш.

Comment: это не автоматически, это в следствие атаки

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Задача решена при помощи утилиты CurrPorts от NierSoft
Спасибо всем за ответы!